# Overriding RxAndroid Schedulers For Testing

Tags: android, testing, rx-java

I've seen RxImmediateSchedulerRule usage to override schedulers for testing.But in my case,it doesn't work as I'm using another kind of schedulers -ThreadExecutor and PostExecutionThread from android10 cleanarchitecture github repo.

```
class UseCase(val repo: Repo, val threadExecutor: ThreadExecutor, val postExecutionThread: PostExecutionThread){
    fun execute() = repo.getData()
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.from(threadExecutor))
    .observeOn(postExecutionThread.scheduler)
}
```

I'm able to override scheduler in observeOn method with below code.

```
whenever(postExecutionThread.scheduler).thenReturn(Schedulers.trampoline())
```

But I didn't find way to override scheduler in subscribeOn method.How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the below test implementation of `ThreadExecutor` to the constructor of your `UseCase` in the test code. This is actually a factory function, which I prefer over derived classes in such cases (but you could use a derived class as well).

```
fun immediateExecutor() : ThreadExecutor {
    return object : ThreadExecutor {
        override fun run(command: Runnable) {
            command.run()
        }
    }
}
```

It just runs commands immediately, which should be sufficient for unit testing your use cases.

Comment: Thanks @Janos Breuer! Your solution works perfectly. And I've just found another solution which might need to change constructor declaration (https://stackoverflow.com/a/43320828/6270674)